# swift 3 - AVCaptureSession image shrinking

Tags: avfoundation, avcapturesession

I'm displaying a custom camera that is the width of the device x width of the device.

When I take the image and display it on an ImageView, it looks like it shrinks a bit.

Here's how I'm taking the image:

```
 func takePictureTapped(){
        print("Picture button tapped")

        cameraQueue.sync {
            let orientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation(rawValue: UIDevice.current.orientation.rawValue)!

            guard let videoConnection: AVCaptureConnection = imageOutput.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) else {
                //Error
                return
            }

            videoConnection.videoOrientation = orientation

            imageOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection, completionHandler: { buffer, error in

                if let buffer = buffer,
                    let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(buffer),
                     let image = UIImage(data: imageData) {

                        self.imageTaken(image: image)

                }
            })

        }
}
```

ImageTaken() simply takes the image and displays it in an imageview of the same size. Why is the image shrinking a bit? I want it to be displayed in the imageview just how it looked when it was taken.

Before taken:
[image]
After taken:

[image]

Comment: can you explain how you're displaying the custom camera?

Comment: Rhythmic, I used the following example:http://drivecurrent.com/using-swift-and-avfoundation-to-create-a-custom-camera-view-for-an-ios-app/ Thanks for your help!